# iframe full screen per button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to embed in my web page a section of a publication from wikipedia within a box (as it is in the iframe code), and if the user is really interested, they can click on the full screen button to display the Wikipedia page in full-screen, *without redirecting it, without opening a new window*.

If you could improve and clean code welcome

Image 1 = the embedded page is displayed

Image 2 = is what the pressional full screen currently does

Image 3 = is what I actually require you to do when I press the full screen button

The code I have is the following.

```
<! doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<script> function launchFullScreen (element) {
if (element.requestFullScreen) {
element.requestFullScreen ();
} else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
element.mozRequestFullScreen ();
} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
element.webkitRequestFullScreen ();
}
}
// Launch in full screen in browsers that support it
function cancelFullScreen () {
if (document.cancelFullScreen) {
document.cancelFullScreen ();
} else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
document.mozCancelFullScreen ();
} else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
document.webkitCancelFullScreen ();
}
}
</script>
<button onclick = "launchFullScreen (document.documentElement);"> Enter full screen </button>
<button onclick = "cancelFullScreen ();"> Exit full screen </button>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class = "youtube-embed-wrapper" style = "position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden"> <iframe __idm_id __ = "137667585" allowfullscreen = "" frameborder = "0" height = "360" src = "https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Portada" style = "position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100% ; height: 100% "width =" 640 "> </iframe> </div>


<p> & nbsp; </p>
</div>

<p style = "text-align: justify;"> <span style = "font-size: 18px;"> <img alt = "" height = "450" ​​src = "/ courses / WEBINARFATRI / document / webinar -german -rodriguez-1.png "width =" 500 "/> </span> </p>
<style type = "text / css"> body {}
</style>
<style type = "text / css"> body {}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtKp3.jpg)

Comment: do you want full-screen, or just to fill the tab/browser window?

Comment: Does this code work or not?

Comment: Hello correct I want the tab to be filled